# Dropdown to modify textbox value with knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

The following html/JavaScript is my attempt to make a dropdown menu modify two values in text boxes.

```
<select type="date" data-bind="options: dateranges, 
optionsText: 'rangeName', optionsCaption: 'Choose' ">
<select>
<br>
<input type="date" data-bind="value: rangeStartVal , valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<br />
<input type="date" data-bind="value: rangeStopVal , valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var RangeValue = function (name, startVal, stopVal) {
        this.rangeName = name;
        this.rangeStartVal = startVal;
        this.rangeStopVal = stopVal;
        return
    };

    var viewModel = {

        dateranges: ko.observableArray([
        new RangeValue("Today", "2014-04-28", "2014-04-28"),
        new RangeValue("Yesterday", "2014-04-27", "2014-04-27"),
        new RangeValue("This Week", "2014-04-28", "2014-05-04"),
        new RangeValue("Last Week", "2014-04-21", "2014-04-27"),]),
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

I want whenever I change the value in the dropdown to modify the values in each of the textboxes one is the start value, and one is the stop value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a property that will hold the selected range. And than bind your inputs to the rangeStartVal and rangeStopVal properties of the selectedRange.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LV3gG/)

Also you will notice the **IF** binding, it will basically not bind anything and hide elements unless you have selectedRange set.

```
<select type="date" data-bind="options: dateranges, 
optionsText: 'rangeName', optionsCaption: 'Choose', value: selectedRange ">
<select>
<br>
<div data-bind="if: selectedRange() != undefined">
<input type="date" data-bind="value: selectedRange().rangeStartVal , valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<br />
<input type="date" data-bind="value: selectedRange().rangeStopVal , valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</div>
```

Your View Model:

```
var RangeValue = function (name, startVal, stopVal) {
    var self = this;
    self.rangeName = name;
    self.rangeStartVal = startVal;
    self.rangeStopVal = stopVal;
};

function myVm() {
    var self = this;
    self.dateranges = ko.observableArray([
        new RangeValue("Today", "2014-04-28", "2014-04-28"),
        new RangeValue("Yesterday", "2014-04-27", "2014-04-27"),
        new RangeValue("This Week", "2014-04-28", "2014-05-04"),
        new RangeValue("Last Week", "2014-04-21", "2014-04-27")]);

    self.selectedRange = ko.observable();
}
var viewModel = new myVm();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select type="date" data-bind="options: dateranges,
            optionsText: 'rangeName', optionsCaption: 'Choose',value:key ">
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="date" data-bind="value: selectedRangeObj.start , valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    <br />
    <input type="date" data-bind="value: selectedRangeObj.end , valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function viewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.dateranges = [
                {key: "Today", start: "2014-04-28", end: "2014-04-28"},
                {key: "Yesterday", start: "2014-04-27", end: "2014-04-27"},
                {key: "This Week", start: "2014-04-28", end: "2014-04-05"},
                {key: "This Week", start: "2014-04-21", end: "2014-04-27"}];
            self.selectedRange = ko.observable();
            self.selectedRangeObj = ko.computed(function() {
                var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(dateranges(), function(item) {
                    return selectedRange() === item.key;
                });
            }, this);
        }
        var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
    </script>
```

Comment: You don't really need to create ko.computed.